# Not sure if this is appropriate to do -- calling a Spring endpoint from another endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest

Is there a way for me to do this and is it appropriate? I need the data that comes back from an endpoint in a different controller. Would I create a HTTP request on right in the java code?

Please advise if this is an appropriate question for here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider separating the *retrieval* of the data and the *presentation* of the data from your current endpoint in two different classes. After you've done that you can easily have two Spring controllers share the same source of data. One of them is your current Spring controller, the other one is the new one.

Performing an HTTP request from one Spring controller to another one in the same application would introduce a lot of overhead and complexity. I would try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do is to call the service that is generating the data for the controller in the controller that needs the data.

I hope that you've structured your project as an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). If not, you should be addressing that before you do anything else.

Comment: It is, its the project I've been working on. Most of the logic in the controller utilizes the HttpServletRequest, its essentially a passthrough controller that is linking to different WARs in the project. The setup is a little over my head at the moment so I'm just focusing on my task at hand. I was unsure it would be wise to create a service when most of the logic is handling the request?